# Prove system has periodic solutions but no limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limit-cycles

I have the following system

\begin{align*}
         \dot{x} &= -y+xy,\\
         \dot{y} &= x+\frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2)\\
     \end{align*}
I have to prove that this system has periodic solutions but no limit cycles.

My attempt: In order to prove that there exist a periodic solution I change my system into polar form. Thus,

$$\dot{r}=r^2\sin\theta (cos^2\theta+1/2cos(2\theta)),$$

but I cannot conclude anything from this. Another approach that I tried is guess the periodic solution and see if it satisfies the system. The most close thing that I got was a parametrization from a hyperbole but partially satisfies the system. Moreover, for the cycle limit I tried to apply the Bendixon criterion but again I cannot conclude anything.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your equations are equivalent to
$$\dot{r}=r^2\sin\theta (\cos^2\theta+1/2\cos(2\theta)),\dot{\theta}=1$$
So
$$ \frac{\dot{r}}{r^2}=\sin\theta (\cos^2\theta+1/2\cos(2\theta)),\theta=t+c. $$
For simplicity, choosing $c=0$ and integrating w.r.t $t$, one has
$$ \frac{1}{r(t)}-\frac{1}{r_0}=-\int_0^{t} \sin t (\cos^2t+1/2\cos(2t))dt=-\frac1{3}\bigg[3+5\cos(t)+\cos(2t)\bigg]\sin^2(t/2) $$
and hence
$$ r(t)=\frac{r_0}{1-\frac{r_0}{3}\bigg[3+5\cos(t)+\cos(2t)\bigg]\sin^2(t/2)} $$
which implies $r(t)$ is periodic for small $r_0>0$. Clearly if we choose $r_0=3$, and then
$$ \lim_{t\to(\pi/2)^-}r(t)=\infty $$
and hence $r(t)$ don't have a limit cycle.

Comment: One question, the limit is when $t \to \pi/2$?

Comment: How do you get $\dot{\theta}=1$?

Comment: Actually, there is no restrict for $\dot{\theta}$. For simplicity, set  $\dot{\theta}=1$.

Comment: But there is a restriction, if you convert to polar coordinates you will get something different for $\dot{\theta} $

Comment: Or am I wrong??